# Use Oracle 10g BI enterprise edition with Oracle 11g database

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence

Can i use Oracle 10g BI enterprise edition with Oracle 11g database.

please tell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a dump of your Oracle 11g DB and restore it in Oracle 10g.

Some more info you can see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876576/how-to-import-oracle-11g-dump-file-to-10g-oracle